# iPhone Application Loader and Icon File extension

Tags: iphone, ios

So i've got an iPhone app that i've finished updating with high resolution graphics.

Included in the update was adding a new high resolution icon (icon@2x.png)

If i set the "Icon File" key in the -info.plist file to "icon" the icon displays expected on the device, however when i try to upload the application using application loader, it complains saying that the icon file doesn't have an extension.

When i set the "Icon File" key to "icon.png" and load the application to the device the low res icon is shown and not the new pretty one.

My solution was to not use the application loader and instead use itunes connect to load the binary, however since they are doing away with this method of uploading binaries this solution does not seem viable in the long term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple documentation on this subject is incomplete, and even wrong.

Here's the correct way of using high-res icons in your Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>Icon.png</string>
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>Icon.png</string>
    <string>Icon@2x.png</string>
</array>
```

In Xcode, these two keys show up as "Icon file" and "Icon files."